# How to populate 2 array's from one txt file

Tags: java, arrays

I'm not entirely grasping how to populate two arrays from 1 of many txt files that contain two lines of numbers.  Here is my code thus far,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Merge
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] arr1 = new int[7];
    int[] arr2 = new int[9];
    int[] arr3 = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

    try{
        System.out.print("Enter the filename: ");
        String input = scan.nextLine();

        File file = new File(input);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        while(inputFile.hasNext() && a < arr1.length && b < arr2.length){
             arr1[a] = inputFile.nextInt();
             arr2[b] = inputFile.nextInt();
             System.out.println(arr1[a] + " " + arr2[b] + " ");
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    }
}
```

The program compiles and runs but I really don't know what to make of the output and how to begin sorting and merging them.  Do I need another while loop or for loop to traverse the elements individually? 
The text file is values1.txt has the following values.

```
1 25 38 43 57 58 71
2 3 4 26 41 42 59 60 61
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Your question is not clear, please clarify

Comment: Well I want to confirm if the output of my code currently is properly populating arr1 and arr2 from the values1.txt file essentially

Comment: I don't think it is, it is filling values in 0th position of the arrays, increase your 'a' and 'b' variables, i.e. your counters by ++ in your while loop.

Comment: I get an out of bounds error when I increment the counters indicating that only the first array is being filled.

Comment: Your arrays of size 7 and 9, so you will get an out of bounds, if you try putting more elements than it can hold, give an if condition to check the bounds before assigning.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 big problems:

First, it sounds like you want to read the first line into `arr1` and the second line into `arr2`, and that's not what you're doing with:

```
//a = b = 0
while(inputFile.hasNext() && a < arr1.length && b < arr2.length){
     arr1[a] = inputFile.nextInt();
     arr2[b] = inputFile.nextInt();
     a++; 
     b++;
}
```

This is taking the first value (on the first line) and placing it in `arr1[a]`, the second value on *(on the first line)* and placing it in `arr2[b]`, etc. So you'd end up with:

```
arrA = [1, 38, 57, 71, 3, 26, 42]
arrB = [25, 43, 58, 2, 4, 41, 59, 0, 0]
```

You need to break the input file into lines, then iterate through them - we'll get back to that.

Second: The `a++; b++` in my code above, is not in yours - both a and b are always 0, so with each iteration you're just placing two new values in the same slots, replacing the previous ones. So, as you have it written, your code produces:

```
arr1 = [60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
arr2 = [61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Third, that `while` condition is a mess: See @SergeBallesta's answer for one definite problem, and there are other potential ones. As a *general* rule of thumb, anytime you find yourself writing `&&` more than twice in a while/if condition, stop and think hard about whether it could be broken up: ***Writing simple/clean code != writing as few lines as possible***

In this case, breaking it up goes hand in hand with solving our first problem.

The point of the exercise is for *you* to figure out how to do this, so I'm going to leave that to you. Feel free to post a comment if you get stuck/don't understand something I've said.

Also: `Arrays.toString()` gives you a handy way to print the contents of an array. If you throw these two lines at the bottom of your `main`:

```
System.out.println("arr1:" + Arrays.toString(arr1));
System.out.println("arr2:" + Arrays.toString(arr2));
```

You'll see the final outputs each time you run it.

Comment: I updated my code in notepad++ for the counters but I get an out of bounds error indicating that only the first array is being filled.

Answer (score 0):

It will break because you have a total of 9 + 7 = 16 integers. With your loop, you will read 2 * 8  and `arr1` is only of size 7. So you will only read 14 integers and won't affect them correctly.

You need to read a full line at a time into a string, splits that string on spaces (`"\s+"` see javadoc of `String.split()` ...)and convert each item to an int to store it in your arrays.

Comment: Reading up on it now, but going off your comment, what you're saying is it will break up the text file values into strings then individually split up the integers into separate strings?

Comment: @user4225587 : As in your code arr1 is size 7, and arr2 is size 9 and first line has 7 items and second has 9, I thought that you wanted as result `arr1[] = {1, 25, 38, 43, 57, 58, 71}` and `arr2 =  {2, 3, 4, 26, 41, 42, 59, 60, 61}`. If it is that you should effectively read line by line, split the lines into array of strings and convert the individual strings into integers.